# Django TrigramSimilarity search gives no such function: SIMILARITY

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to do a TrigramSimilarity search in my Django project.
As written in the django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#trigramsimilarity) i have done the following import: `from django.contrib.postgres.search import TrigramSimilarity`;
I have also added `'django.contrib.postgres'` inside the `INSTALLED_APPS` of the `settings.py` file.

The error does not come instantly: i receive this error `Django TrigramSimilarity search gives no such function: SIMILARITY` once i do something with the queryset.
For example if i want to do a simple operation such as a print(), the error comes. The code below is what i have done

```
articles = Article.objects.annotate(
    similarity=TrigramSimilarity('name', search_str),
).filter(similarity__gt=0.3).order_by('-similarity')
print(articles) #that line causes the error (no such function: SIMILARITY)
```

I have literally searched for everything, but it seems that no one had this error before.
I have exactly did what the documentation says -> [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#trigramsimilarity)

Maybe there is another way to do a TrigramSimilarity, but as i said before i read the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add pg_trgm extension to your postgres.
And after that postgres will understand TrigramSimilarity.

Answer (score 0):

I solved creating manually a function that reproduces Trigraman Similarity Search.